# Custom nuget feed, VS doesn't see package as installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

Hi all
I have a local Nuget source with a package containing some default items I want in my projects (default corporate models and styles and some default pages). It is only copying items in to the project and adding a connection string to the web.config, nothing fancy.

I can install the package via the Package Manager Console and the GUI. However, it never shows as installed. This means that I cannot update it nor can I uninstall it. If I go to the GUI, it shows the package as not installed, even though it has added all items to the project and has a folder for the package in the packages directory.

Also, I want to use this NuGet package to overwrite some files that already exist in the default MVC project (such as AccountController and LogonUserControl.ascx). Can this be done or will I need to start off with the blank MVC template instead of the default?

Packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
 <package id="MyCompanyMVC" version="1.1" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Does you project end up with a packages.config? Are you sure you build the package correctly? Is there a packages folder?

Comment: Yes there is a packages folder and it contains my package, that is why I am so mystified by the error! The package was created manually in the Nuget Package Explorer so I would hope it built the package correctly!

Comment: Do you have a content folder in your package with the files that apply to your project? Did you follow the instructions here http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package? There are conventional folders that you're supposed to use in order to build your package.

Comment: Yes, all of my files are contained in a content folder. When I run install-package, all of the files go where they should be.

Comment: What version of nuget are you using? And is there a packages.config in that project with your package listed?

Comment: There is a packages.config which correctly lists my package, I have added content of packages.config to original post. How do I determine which version of nuget I am using?

Answer (score 1):

NuGet won't overwrite files - I don't believe there's a way to force it, however you could probably "work around" this by using a PowerShell script (tools/install.ps1) to delete the old file and rename your injected file to have the required name.